# pandas iterate dataframe day wise

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to iterate over data-frame daywise.

My data looks like this:

```
                         open    high     low   close   volume
date                                                              
2019-12-18 09:15:00+05:30  182.10  182.30  180.55  181.30  4252638
2019-12-18 09:30:00+05:30  181.30  183.45  181.00  183.20  5869850
2019-12-18 09:45:00+05:30  183.35  184.50  183.05  183.25  5201947
2019-12-18 10:00:00+05:30  183.25  183.30  182.45  182.90  2029440
2019-12-18 10:15:00+05:30  182.95  183.25  181.50  182.00  2613453
...                           ...     ...     ...     ...      ...
2019-12-24 14:15:00+05:30  175.40  175.70  175.10  175.40   480322
2019-12-24 14:30:00+05:30  175.40  175.60  174.65  174.80  1193108
2019-12-24 14:45:00+05:30  174.80  176.10  174.75  175.55  1765370
2019-12-24 15:00:00+05:30  175.50  175.75  174.90  175.50  1369208
2019-12-24 15:15:00+05:30  175.45  175.75  175.20  175.40  2010583
```

I have tried

```
(df['date'] >= "18-12-2019 09:00:00") & (df['date'] <= "18-12-2019 16:00:00")
```

but I don't want data for specific date I want split current dataframe into multiple data frame on the basis of date and store it in an array. How can I do that?

Expected output:

```
res = [] # list of dataframes length =  number of days


res[0] = 

                         open    high     low   close   volume
date                                                              
2019-12-18 09:15:00+05:30  182.10  182.30  180.55  181.30  4252638
2019-12-18 09:30:00+05:30  181.30  183.45  181.00  183.20  5869850
2019-12-18 09:45:00+05:30  183.35  184.50  183.05  183.25  5201947
2019-12-18 10:00:00+05:30  183.25  183.30  182.45  182.90  2029440
2019-12-18 10:15:00+05:30  182.95  183.25  181.50  182.00  2613453


res[1] = 
                          open    high     low   close   volume
date                                                              
2019-12-19 09:15:00+05:30  182.10  182.30  180.55  181.30  4252638
2019-12-19 09:30:00+05:30  181.30  183.45  181.00  183.20  5869850
2019-12-19 09:45:00+05:30  183.35  184.50  183.05  183.25  5201947
2019-12-19 10:00:00+05:30  183.25  183.30  182.45  182.90  2029440
2019-12-19 10:15:00+05:30  182.95  183.25  181.50  182.00  2613453

...
...
res[n] = 
2019-12-24 14:15:00+05:30  175.40  175.70  175.10  175.40   480322
2019-12-24 14:30:00+05:30  175.40  175.60  174.65  174.80  1193108
2019-12-24 14:45:00+05:30  174.80  176.10  174.75  175.55  1765370
2019-12-24 15:00:00+05:30  175.50  175.75  174.90  175.50  1369208
2019-12-24 15:15:00+05:30  175.45  175.75  175.20  175.40  2010583
```

different date data spitted and placed in array.

Comment: Can you show your expected out come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `groupby` method and aggregate all other columns in the way you like. For instance:

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.date)['open'].sum()
```

A OHLC would become:

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.date).agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
})
```

Comment: But I want all values of that day not aggregated values

Comment: ok It worked `df = df.groupby(df.date.dt.day)

for x in df:
    print(x)`

Comment: The `groupby` object have that. If you do a `pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df.date.dt.day))` you will notice a dataframe with one row for each date and, on the second column, a dataframe with all lines regarding the date from the original df.

Comment: I think there can be a problem when data of multiple month and year are present it end up grouping them to 31 only

Comment: `df = df.groupby(df.date.dt.date)` this would be better.